# Is there a way for switch 2 words in MySQL row field

Tags: mysql

I would want to switch 2 words (firstName lastName) in a mysql row's fields

example :

I have a column 'persons' with a field :
Jonh Smith

I would want to switch to : Smith Jonh

I searched a lot for a MySQL function or snippet but found no way.

Comment: Is it possible the `person` column filled with 3 words? Let's say `Jhon Doe Smith`?

Comment: unfortunately, I was thinking about the regexp for this case, but if I can already find the solution in two words.. magic lol

Comment: See the answer by @arun-krish below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this update if the field has only two words

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET persons = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(persons, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),' ',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(persons, ' ', 1), ' ', -1))
```